# How to customize message to facebook share button

Tags: html, facebook

I would like to put a facebook share button on my site that shares a specific sentence as someone's status.  Currently, I have the share button working, but I can't specify the status I'm trying to share.  The `#status`  changes often with javascript so it's variable.

HTML in body:

```
<p id='status'>Example of status to share on user's profile</p>

<script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436'); return false;}</script><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

In short, I would like to be able to change the text highlighted in red and replace it with my own

[image]

Comment: You are not allowed to pre-fill the message that the user shares, it has to be a 100% user-generated. Please go read FB Platform Policies.

Comment: @CBroe under overview, 2nd photo https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share

Comment: So you don’t want that “specific sentence” as the user _status_, but only share a link with a specific description. (Yes, it pays off to be clear and precise.) The documentation page already links to further explanations on how to accomplish that – so read a little more please. (Or do some more research, this topic is everything but a new one.)

Comment: @CBroe  i didn't mean to be rude.  sorry if i came off that way.  thanks for the link.